# Searching Multiple Columns From Single Source Sheet in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-filter

I have a Sheet where I have all of my data entered. I have been able to filter the information to other sheets no issues when only searching in one column. I am having issues when trying to search 2 columns at the same time.

On the Source Page, I have my date listed under the following headers: Player Name (A), OVR (B), Series (C), Primary (D), Secondary (E), Bats (F), Throws (G), How To Acquire (H), Team of Card (I) & Teams Played For (J).

For most sheets, I have been able to use the following formulae:

```
=SORT(FILTER(Cards!1:1000,SEARCH("Giants",Cards!J1:J1000)),2,false,1,true)
```

My issue comes from when I try to search both Primary and Secondary at the same time. I was able to use a query that searched both columns but am unable to do using SEARCH.

Answer (score 0):

It is always challenging (and sometimes impossible) to provide meaningful answers based on snippets of information. However, given what you've shared here, try setting up your two-column search the same way as your one-column search, but structure the SEARCH portions this way:

`SEARCH(ColD parameters) + SEARCH(ColE parameters)`

The `+` serves as an `OR`.

Answer (score 0):

This may be easier to do with `query()`:

```
=query( 
  Cards!1:1000, 
  "where J contains 'Giants' 
   and lower(D) = 'yes' 
   and lower(E) = 'no' 
   order by B desc, A asc", 
  1
)
```

See the [query language help page](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#Language_Syntax).